# Powershell asking for git RSA passphrase on every pull instead of on startup?

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I've installed PoshGit and I've set up my RSA key with github and in my ~\.ssh folder, but PowerShell still prompts me to enter a passphrase on every pull/push. I've followed all the instructions [given here](http://www.imtraum.com/blog/streamline-git-with-powershell/). My powershell profile looks like so:

```
$env:path += ";" + (Get-Item "Env:ProgramFiles(x86)").Value + "\Git\bin"
. 'C:\Users\Caleb\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1'
cd ~\Documents\GitHub\travefy
```

Here's what happens. How do I get it to only ask me on startup?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I need to run

```
> ssh-add
```

I'm not sure why this wasn't mentioned in any of the docs on github.com.

Comment: Interesting... the last thing `Start-SshAgent` (called by default in the example profile) does is `Add-SshKey`, which should call `ssh-add` for you. Could you open an issue on GitHub for this?

Comment: I realize this is old, but I'm having the same problem and it's not related to `ssh-add`.  In fact, I can verify my ssh keys are working with ssh and ssh-agent. `ssh -T git@github.com` works as expected and `ssh-add -l` shows my key is loaded.  But `git pull` prompts for the key pasphrase every time. I'm stumped.

Comment: You need to get the ssh-agent to run in Powershell by using the command that comes bundled with Git for Windows, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153372/1548601

Answer (score 5):

May you need to configure Git to use the Windows 10 implementation of OpenSSH by issuing the following command in Powershell:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

This worked for me.
Source: [danieldogeanu](https://gist.github.com/danieldogeanu/16c61e9b80345c5837b9e5045a701c99).