# How to configure VSCode to auto git fetch without asking for SSH key password on Windows 10

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, ssh-keys

Because of this password prompt, auto-fetch, push and pull from VSCode doesn't work. This requires me to manually push/pull from the integrated terminal (which will prompt me a password).

However, when I run `ssh -T git@github.com-work` within the Integrated Terminal of VSCode, I am able to ssh in without a password prompt (which is what I am trying to achieve). I have already added the ssh keys via `ssh-add` and I see them using `ssh-add -L`.
Similarly, I am able to run `ssh -T git@github.com-work` in Windows Terminal without being prompted for the password.

What I wish to achieve is being able to push and pull my repositories using VSCode's inbuilt tools **without the password prompt** every time I attempt to fetch, pull or push. This password prompt is preventing VSCode from auto-fetching or updating my repository by clicking the sync icon on the bottom right (*results in a Permission denied(publickey, keyboard-interactive) prompt from VSCode*)

*Edit*:

Thanks to VonC, I don't have to type my password everytime I run `git fetch` etc. within VSCode's integrated terminal. This was solved by adding

```
$env:GIT_SSH="C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"
```

to my Powershell profile.

However, it still didn't resolve the main issue that VSCode's internal source control tools are unable to pull from `git@github.com-work` but keeps trying at `git@github.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the remote origin URL used by VSCode is actually `github.com-work` (check that in the VSCode output terminal for 'Git').
You don't even need git if your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file does specify `User git` under the entry `Host github.com-work`)

And as [mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/john-auld/a55ffe44e9965623f530cb487e33cebd), launch VSCode (for testing) from a CMD where you have:

```
set GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

Comment: Hmm from VSCode output I can't really see the actual remote origin URL. All I see is 
```
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git fetch
```
however, I can verify on the side (I have Gitlens installed) that the remote is indeed `github.com-work`.  However, it seems that VSCode is unable to understand that and keeps trying to pull from `github.com` instead

Comment: @IcyBloom That is what I though. In command line, go to your local cloned repo, and type `git remote -v` to check.

Comment: Yeapp I just checked it and origins are both `git@github.com-work` for both fetch and push

Comment: @IcyBloom Maybe that is VSCode translating your ssh config file. Or it actually uses another local repository path?

Comment: Hmm I don't think there is another local repository that can be used, and I have ensured that all my ssh config files are the same. :( Plus, through the integrated terminal it is able to git fetch and pull from the right remote, just not through the internal tools (that will output to the readonly terminal)

Comment: @IcyBloom Does the issue persists for any repository accessed with an SSH URL?

Comment: Nope this issue only persists for repositories with a custom remote origin URL such as `git@github.com-work`. I have other personal local repositories using password protected SSH keys as well that uses the default remote URL `git@github.com`. My personal local repositories are able to pull and push through VSCode's tools without a problem

Answer (score 1):

These extra steps did the trick: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63787232/1736679)

The key is to use Windows' OpenSSH as mentioned, but also need to setup git config file to load the key in the Windows Agent.

```
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Tested restarting VSCODE only, not sure yet what happens after restarting windows