# git keeps asking for passphrase after ssh-add on Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, openssh

I'm using git in PowerShell on Windows. I made sure `ssh-agent` is running, and `ssh-add` has my private key.

```
$ Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent

$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com (ED25519)
```

But git still asks for passphrase every time. I tried to debug by setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"`, but couldn't understand what's wrong. Below is the verbose output when I run `git push`.

```
$ git push
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-7f91b4d6
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-7f91b4d6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ED25519 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519 SHA256:2MDH36ZZcM1uf9wQ2tsMj4NROkiGeKUD+CwBsVXrKXY
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519':
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71190226/6309) by [Ajedi32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157054/ajedi32), if you are using [Windows' native implementation of OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) with the [native ssh-agent Windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement), make sure that [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) was configured to use that SSH implementation when you installed it

You can force using another `ssh.exe` with the [`GIT_SSH` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_miscellaneous).

Try also to [start the agent as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386656/6309).

Comment: I installed git again and selected to using native Windows ssh-agent like you mentioned, and it fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these two lines one after another in this order in git bash, Windows WLS or bash on real GNU/Linux.

`eval ssh-agent -s`

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/*_rsa`

it will ask for passphrase in the second command, and that's it. Each additional action you will need to do (which normally requires passphrase) won't ask you for the passphrase.

Comment: Note: the OP is using `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, not `~/.ssh/id_rsa`