# Clone submodules on Windows Powershell not possible

Tags: windows, git, powershell, ssh

I have a project with a submodule configured. It uses a relative path, so it should be checked out via ssh (because I cloned the parent project with ssh).

I did:
`git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`

and the error is on Windows Powershell: `Permission denied`

I think I also found the reason for this. My ssh key is protected with a password. So powershell should ask me for the password as it does when using git clone. But apparently it does not.

So I got a few workarounds:

- Use git bash on Windows (asks me for the passsword and thus works perfectly)
- Don't use a password for ssh
- Don't use ssh

All workarounds are not ideal. So I wonder: Is this a known issue / limitation? Can I do anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

If those submodules are using an SSH URL (check your `.gitmodules`), then you can try and use [an `ssh-agent` in your Powershell session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153372/6309).

Test it with `ssh -Tv remoteUser@remoteServer` (for GitHub remote repositories, that would be `ssh -Tv git@github.com`)

The first query should ask for your SSH passphrase, but after that, you should be able to clone/submodule update without any more prompt.